# NODE GridFStorage with additional data from request doesn't always show up

Tags: node.js, parameter-passing, metadata, multer-gridfs-storage, req

Hey guys i'm confronting a very strange behaviour with GridFs while i try to upload a file:

So i send with formdata my file which i want to upload and a code which will be set in metadata in files,
the files are saved correctly and the originalname field is always added to the metadata but the code field which is a req.body paramater has a very strange behaviour.

files.ts

```
uploadFileFormSubmit(event) {
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('file', event.target.files.item(0));
    formData.append('code', this.courseCode);
    this.fileService.uploadFile(formData).subscribe(res => ....
```

fileService.ts

```
 uploadFile(data): Observable<GeneralResponse> {
    return this.http.post<GeneralResponse>('/files/uploadFile', data);
  }
```

here is the backend part:

files.js (back-end)

```
const storage = new GridFsStorage({
    url: dbUrl,
    file: (req, file) => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          crypto.randomBytes(16, (err, buf) => {
            if (err) {
              return reject(err);
            }
            const filename = buf.toString('hex') + path.extname(file.originalname);
            console.log(req.body)
            const code = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(req.body));  
            console.log(code)
            const fileInfo = {
              filename: filename,
              metadata: {
                originalname: file.originalname,
                materialCode: code.code
              },
              bucketName: 'files'
            };
            resolve(fileInfo);
          });
        });
      }
});
```

As you can see i parse the req.body in order to get my property (i found it here this solution because the req.body was [Object: null prototype] { code: 'myCode'} )

And for some files this code data is passed but not always.
[image: result]

note that there are 2 console.logs(before and after JSON.parse()

the first object null is an excel file,
the second is a pdf
the third is jpg file
the fourth is a png file

maybe it's something with the extensions but i cannot imagine why the req.body sometimes gets parsed 
and the code gets into metadata but other times not :/
So what can cause this behaviour? thanks for help in advance :D